# Change local admin password. Impacts on Oracle and Citrix?

Tags: windows-server-2003, oracle, password, citrix, oracle10g

I need to change the local admin password on some Citrix and Oracle servers.   These servers are in production.
Then we will start using a secure password procedure, and change them every X month.

Before doing anything, I need to know if there can be any impact on such services.
I remember that, with Citrix, there will be no problem if I change the local admin password, but i'm afraid of Oracle.

Do somebody knows how these applicative services can be affected by a local admin password modification ?

Thank you in advance for the hints.

PS : It is Oracle 10gR2 and Citrix PS 4.5.

Comment: And the OS is Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Citrix** - Changing the password will be no problem at all.

**Oracle** - This will only be an issue if the Oracle service is running as Administrator. Find the service in `Control Panel>Administrator Tools>Services`, open it up, and look at the Log On As section to confirm. If it IS running as Administrator just set the new password in there. Also consider changing the user it runs as!

Comment: Thank you, it's okay now.
It uses the SYSTEM user, but this way I saw that some other service starts as Administrator. Okay then, thank you for your answer :)

Comment: 1.5 hours later than my answer but quite the same content...you could have edited mine instead of adding another one.

Answer (score 1):

As you've said - Citrix will definitely be fine.

I don't know about Oracle.

Comment: Thank you for this confirmation.
There is half the answer now.
I have googled it up, but there is not much people talking about local admin pass change and Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

They can be affected when running as local administrator. Which you never ever should do!

So, open up services.msc search for the according services and check the column "Log On As". "Administrator" should not be listed and you are good to go.